# Property 'fitBounds' does not exist on type 'Map | LayerGroup<any>'

Tags: typescript, leaflet, vuejs3

I am converting some old (working) javascript (that uses Leaflet) into Typescript. One line that won't compile is `map.fitBounds(bounds)` :

```
var map: Map | LayerGroup<any> | null = null;
map = L.map(.........)
...
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

giving the error in the title (`Property 'fitBounds' does not exist on type 'Map | LayerGroup<any>'.`).

I have imported the types:

```
import type { Map, LayerGroup } from 'leaflet';
```

and I can see in leaflet's `index.d.ts` that `fitBounds` is defined:

```
export class Map extends Evented {
  ...
  ...
  fitBounds(bounds: LatLngBoundsExpression, options?: FitBoundsOptions): this;
  ...
   remove(): this;
  ....
}
```

so why is this error occuring? The project is using Vue3, and this file is a `.vue` file,  but I don't *think* that is relevant to my question - please correct me if I'm wrong!
As a test, I have tried to use other `Map` methods, e.g. `zoomIn()` and `remove()` : the former fails, the latter does not. All methods are listed in the same class in `index.d.ts`

Comment: Does `fitBounds` exist on `LayerGroup`?

Comment: no, it's only a method for `Map`

Comment: Well there you go, it's not safe then.

Comment: `remove()` isn't in `LayerGroup` either. but that works OK. see my edits

Comment: Yes it is... https://tsplay.dev/wRAO1W

Comment: Hmmm - thanks for the link to the TS playground, but that seems hapy with `fitBounds`: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3nAsgQzAGjgBkdEUoBxKCAVzDgF84AzakOAcgBsUdmeYHANwBYAFDikqOAA04AXmKlyVWmADaAIigoQEAG4pNAXSFwA9ObgoAHsADOMe5ORoAmgux4tzYDABCtAB2ACb2JmaW1naO9kA).

Comment: although if I remove the import of `LayerGroup` my problem goes away. The import was suggested by intelllisense....